# Logout issue MVC3, C#

Tags: c#, session, logout

I have published website on IIS. After login I'm clicking on menu bar, then system is logging out my session.  So want to know what will be possible causes... that I need to check. The click is not particular tab as well as not first click, this is random click.

Comment: Did you leave the session inactive for a period of time?

Comment: @DavidBeaumont It's MVC which advises against using sessions, login persistence might have been turned off when logged in, but this shouldn't log him out right after logging in and clicking a menu tab. Without code or how he logs in, it's impossible to say

Comment: @David  No i'm not leaving session inactive. This is happening after click on menu bar  and buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes of session expires when application pool is recycle,

If you have any code that file in bin folder modifies or create than this type of issue happns.

Comment: MVC projects shouldn't be using sessions

Comment: I have set application pool recycle setting to false. still same issue

Comment: Have you write any files or modify files in bin folder?

Comment: Finally got the issue. Issue is on load balancer side.    All the request during a particular session is not going the to single application server.  Due to switching application server in between session, the session variable got cleared. Due this  logout happens...

Comment: yeah....you have to set session state out proc and shared btween all application server..